# What is the typeface used on the 'red box' Basic D&D boxed set exterior logo?

Tags: content-identification, dnd-becmi, fonts

Just what the title says. The typeface is not Filmotype's Quentin which was used for the logo in the first version of *AD&D*.

[Filmotype Quentin](https://fontsinuse.com/typefaces/12101/filmotype-quentin):

[image: Advanced Dungeons & Dragons in Quentin]

What is the typeface below?

[image: Dungeons & Dragons from Basic boxed set]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Masquerade

I followed fontsinuse.com's Related Typefaces (which even has a convenient hover preview) and found among them [Masquerade](https://fontsinuse.com/typefaces/32139/masquerade) by the late Martin Wait then working for Letraset:

[image: image of font name in font]

It's a commercial typeface from 1977, so it certainly existed as an option to use. For ease of comparison, here's a reproduction with the same white-on-pink text (it'll look sharper because I used hard white, and there's no jpg artefacting. Ignore the ampersand and reg. mark):

[image: reproduction of logo using font]

Which is *strikingly* similar to the original, in a way I'm quite confident it is the typeface in question. It just has to be.

There's unlikely to be any formal (or even informal) relation between Wait or Letraset and TSR and the use for D&D. The most likely explaination is that it was simply a commercial typeface that was available to use. Possibly chosen for its similarity to the typeface used for the Moldvay version two years prior, which is [similar but different](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/File:Basic_1.jpg).

Comment: Doing an image overlay with the  "A", "S", "Q", "E", "R", and "D" letters, I believe you are correct: these are identical fonts. (D doesn't quite line up, but it's capitalized in the D&D logo, so that makes sense)

Comment: @Exempt-Medic Definitely appears to be pixel perfect based on my Microsoft paint skills.

Comment: You are awesome, I wish I could up-vote you again. :) That said, it will be nice if you or another answerer can provide the kind of documentary evidence @HeyICanChan is asking for. Speaking of which, HeyICanChan, if you look closely at the red box you will see that the red of the box is slightly different than the red of the logo characters: I think the designers used 'press on' type like [Letraset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letraset), so Martin may have had no formal relationship with TSR?